IC identification for isolated Power supply
I want to identify 3 integrated circuits on the mornsun ura2415s-6wr3 and find their datasheets.

NCE P0120Q 1XQQ1


1103C H2

its look like opto isolator ic

GA 232  0R 3H

What topology do these types of isolated dc dc supplies generally use?
Any knowledge?




The top one is a NCE Power NCEP0120Q.

(Source: szlcsc.com)

The second one is a Mornsun SCM1103C PWM controller.


Third one is probably an Orient OR-3H7 optocoupler. I think the last character is a 7, but it's hard to see in your picture.


Yeap thats right  thanks, ım wondering the main isolated driver

@Electronx I think I found the rest of the components.

thats great ,how you search it ?
